# Highmaps in React using lat/lon not working

Tags: reactjs, highmaps

I used HighMaps in react.js in that want to plot points using latitude and longitude. i import proj4 also...But the error shows like Using latitude/longitude functionality in Highmaps requires the Proj4js library to be loaded..please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

1. First Install npm proj4 then add this code into seperate component and connect

   import proj4 from 'proj4';

   if(typeof window !== 'undefined') {

   window.proj4 = window.proj4 || proj4;

   }

   export default proj4;